# Prepending to a string

Tags: c, string, concatenation

What is the most efficient way to prepend to a C string, using as little memory as possible?

I am trying to reconstruct the path to a file in a large directory tree.

Here's an idea of what I was doing before:

```
char temp[LENGTH], file[LENGTH];
file = some_file_name;

while (some_condition) {
    parent_dir = some_calculation_that_yields_name_of_parent_dir;
    sprintf(temp, "%s/%s", parent_dir, file);
    strcpy(file, temp);
}
```

This seems a bit clunky though.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You say large scales, that leads me to beleive you need it to be FAST.  Which is more important in your case? Fast or small?

Comment: I would say that fast/efficient is definitely more important.

Comment: @d03boy:  Whoops, forgot about that one.  Thanks.

Comment: Can some_calculation_that_yields_name_of_parent_dir somehow return not just parent dir, but the length of parent_dir as well?
(this would spare a strlen in some algorithms posted below and allow you to make only one allocation, at the end.)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Copying can hardly be avoided if you want it in the same memory chunk. If the allocated chunk is large enough you *could* use `memmove` to shift the original string by the length of what you want to prepend and then copy that one into the beginning, but I doubt this is less "clunky". It would however save you extra memory (again, granted that the original chunk has enough free space for them both).

Something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void prepend(char* s, const char* t);

/* Prepends t into s. Assumes s has enough space allocated
** for the combined string.
*/
void prepend(char* s, const char* t)
{
    size_t len = strlen(t);
    memmove(s + len, s, strlen(s) + 1);
    memcpy(s, t, len);
}

int main()
{
    char* s = malloc(100);
    strcpy(s, "file");
    prepend(s, "dir/");

    printf("%s\n", s);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That makes sense.  Instead of the for loop, couldn't you use a memcpy?

Comment: prepend() could be optimized more by using C99 "restrict" qualifiers on s and t.

Comment: If `s` is longer than `t` it will be cut off. The third argument in memmove should take the length of `s` into account.

Comment: @Joseph: Both ways doesn't work. if t len is taken it clips off. and does nothing if s len is used. Please everyone do check and test the given answer. Sometimes it passes some tests, so make sure one has tested it thoroughly.

Comment: It should be: memmove(s + len, s, strlen(s));  You want to copy strlen(s) bytes from source to dest.

Comment: @brooksbp You're exactly right. Just needed this, thanks

Comment: @EliBendersky You should change your answer.

Comment: @yentup, @brooksbp: changed to move `strlen(s)+1` bytes - the trailing 0 has to be moved too.

Comment: A safer version would also have argument for the size of the buffer, so it would not write out of bounds.

Answer (score 7):

If you don't need the string to be stored in order, but only *appear* to be in order, then use a thing called a "rope." (It's made of lots of "string", see.)

I believe it's basically a vector (in C terms, an array) of `struct { char *begin; char *end };`

In C++ it implements all the std::string functions. In C you'd need to write (or get a library of) replacement functions for all the strxxx() functions.

What the "rope" would do to prepend a string to another string is simply insert a new begin,end pair pointing at the new piece of string. It might also have to copy the new piece of string, if it's a temporary pointer. Or it can just take ownership of the string if it's an allocated string.

A rope is very good for large strings. But anything under about 8 KB is faster to handle with memmove and memcpy.

Comment: +1 I like this suggestion. Even if what is needed eventually is an array of chars, if is easy at the end to compute the final length of the rope and to allocate a right-sized buffer (and to copy **once**).

Answer (score 3):

sprintf() is generally not 'fast'. Since you know it's pre-pending memmove() twice would probably be preferable for speed.

If you're allocating the strings with malloc() originally you might consider using realloc() to resize the character arrays so they can contain the new string.

```
   char* p = malloc( size_of_first_string );
   ...
   p = realloc( p, size_of_first_string + size_of_prepended_string + 1 );
   memmove( p + size_of_prepended_string, p, size_of_first_string );
   memmove( p, prepended_string, size_of_prepended_string );
```

Comment: memcpy() is often much faster if you *know* the source and destination do not overlap. So it might be worth checking the realloc return and use memcpy if it returned a different pointer.

Comment: You don't need to + 1 in `realloc` to account for terminating `\0` char?

Comment: @Geremia is correct. Don't forget to add one to the size of the realloc. I'll edit it to insert that

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps I'm confused, but I believe that a prepend is the same as appending with the strings swapped.  So instead of *prepending* "Hello" to "World", the string "World" can be **appended** to "Hello":

```
const char world[] = "World";
const char hello[] = "Hello";

// Prepend hello to world:
const unsigned int RESULT_SIZE = sizeof(world) + sizeof(hello) + 2 * sizeof('\0');
char * result = malloc(RESULT_SIZE);
if (result)
{
  strcpy(result, hello);
  strcat(result, world);
  puts("Result of prepending hello to world: ");
  puts(result);
  puts("\n");
}
```

Also, the main waste of execution time is finding the end of a string.  If the strings were stored with the length, the end could be calculated faster.

Comment: Your idea is right, but it doesn't work very well in this case because there are more than two strings.  I need to iteratively prepend to a string.  If you put your strcpy and strcat lines in a while loop, on the second iteration you'd have to either create a new char array or move what was stored in "result" so that you had room to prepend.

Answer (score 1):

You could maintain the string starting from the end. Since you seem to know the maxSize already...

So basically if file initially was (foo.txt)

```
[] [] [] [] [] [f] [o] [o] [.] [t] [x] [t] [\0]
             ^
             |
          lastEmpty
```

Now if you add a parent dir a/ it will look like

```
[] [] [] [a] [/] [f] [o] [o] [.] [t] [x] [t] [\0]
       ^      
       |      
    lastEmpty
```

So the code will look something like (there might be bugs, but you get the idea).

```
char temp[LENGTH], file[LENGTH]; 
int lastEmpty = put_at_end(some_file_name, file);  
// lastEmpty points to right most empty slot

while (some_condition) { 
    parent_dir = some_calculation_that_yields_name_of_parent_dir; 

    int len = strlen(parent_dir);
    char *tmp = parent_dir + len -1;

    while (lastEmpty > 0) {
        file[lastEmpty] = *tmp;
        lastEmpty --;
        tmp--;
    }
}
```

Since I suppose we could expect parent_dir to be small, going over it twice should be ok. If you want to pass around the file string, you can just use `file+lastEmpty+1`.

Answer (score 1):

You can climb to the top of the directory tree keeping the names as you go along, then paste the names together all at once.  At least then you aren't doing unnecessary copies by pushing onto the front.

```
int i = 0;
int j;

char temp*[MAX_DIR_DEPTH], file[LENGTH];

while (some_condition) {
    temp[i++] = some_calculation_that_yields_name_of_parent_dir;        
}

char *pCurrent = file;    
for( j = i-1; j > 0; j-- )
{
    strcpy(pCurrent, temp[j]);
    pCurrent += strlen(temp[j]);
    *pCurrent++ = '\';
}
strcpy(pCurrent, filename);
*pCurrent = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution has no more copying than necessary.  It does require one strlen, so if the directory name retrieval can return the number of bytes copied or if you can precalculate the parent dir string length, you can optimize that away.

```
void GetFilename(char *pFile)
{
    strcpy(pFile, "someFile");
}

void GetParentDir(char *pDir)
{
    strcpy(pDir, "/parentdir");
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    char path[1024];
    GetParentDir(path);
    int dirSize = strlen(path);
    path[dirSize] = '/';
    GetFilename(path + dirSize + 1);
    printf(path);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I leave a buffer at left and at right of the array. You have to hold two index but if you have to do it a lot of times (otherweise there would be no problem for efficency) it worts it. The two index I suggest to be ]s;e], one included and one not:

```
 #define BUFSIZE 256
 #define LEFTBUF 20
 struct mstring
 {
   char * string;
   unsigned s;
   unsigned e;
  }
  void checkbuf(struct mstring *value, int newstringlen, char   leftorright)
  {
  //have fun here
  }
  char * concat (struct mstring * value, char * str)
  {
       checkbuf(value, strlen(value,str), 'r');
       int i=0;
       while (str[i])
            value->string[value->e++]=str[i++];
   }
   char * set(struct mstring * value, char * str)
   {
        value->e=LEFTBUF;
        value->s=LEFTBUF;
        concat( value,str);

   }

  char * prepend (struct mstring * value, char * str)
  {
       checkbuf(value, strlen(value,str), 'l');
       int i=strlen(value,str)-1;
       while (i>=0)
            value->string[--value->s]=str[i--];
   }
  int main()
  {
      struct mstring * mystring= (struct mstring *) malloc(sizeof(struct mstring) );
      mystring->string=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*BUFSIZE);
      set( mystring,"World");
      prepend(mystring,"Hallo")

  }
```

then you have to prepare a function for fill substrings...