# C++ read line from text file and edit

Tags: c++

first i want  to apologize for my english. I want to create a program that reads each line from a .txt file and adds for each line @" in front and " at the end. Example: @" i like apples". This is my code so far that replaces ".", "?" and ":" but i don't want that.

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <fstream.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <values.h>
int main()
{ ifstream f;
f.open("lala.txt");
if(!f)
{                           
    cout<<"Eroare la deschiderea fisierului!"<<endl;

}
char s[100],x;
int i,n=0, k=0;
ofstream g("adinarez.txt");
f.seekg(0,ios::beg); //ne pozitionam la inceputul fisierului
while(f)
{
f.get(x);
s[k]=x;
    n++; k++;
}
    f.close();

for (i=2; i<n-1; i++)
if((s[i]>=65) && (s[i]<=90))
  { s[i-1]='\"';
   s[i-2]='@';}
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
if(s[i]=='.' || s[i]=='?' || s[i]==':' || s[i]=='\0')
s[i+1]='\"';
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
g<<s[i];
g.close();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: First of all, the people on this site are not here to solve your homework for you. But most importantly, use Google before asking! Basic string manipulation is covered in countless tutorials and websites all over the internet.

Comment: You must be using an ancient compiler. Any halfway recent compiler will not even go beyond the first line, because `#include <iostream.h>` is not valid C++. You should first get a modern compiler and *then* reevaluate all problems you might experience.

Comment: >first i want to apologize for my english. < Your code formatting is what really hurts us.

Comment: belive me i searched all day for a tutorials and i made this program. this is not my homework. i want to edit 20.000 questions and add them @"  " and i can't find a better solution.

Comment: Here are some links from internet: [Reading file line by line](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Read_a_file_line_by_line), [Prepending a string in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2328182/prepending-to-a-string), [Prepending a string in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17110407/best-way-to-add-a-char-prefix-to-a-char-in-c)

Comment: @myaut I'm not sure I'd recommend any of those links.

Comment: @myaut The first is too generic it has more noise than anything else for someone learning C++.  It also presents two versions, without mentioning that the second is very particular to a non-standard library that isn't widely used.  The second is pure C.  And the first answer in the last is pure obfuscation.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, if you're processing line oriented input, use
`std::getline` to read line by line; don't use `std::istream::get`.
Also, you need to check the status of the stream *after* the read, not
before.  Something like `while ( std::getline( f, line )`.  And `line`
should be an `std::string`, so you don't have to worry about overflow.
(Sort of.  If a line contains more memory than the program can allocate,
you'll crash with an uncaught `std::bad_alloc`.  But that will be a lot
more than a hundred characters.)  Once you've got the line, you can use
the `<<` operator on the output stream to output it.  Along with
anything else you want to output.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly you understand offer this way:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>


int main()
{
    std::string line;
    std::ifstream myfile("1.txt");
    std::ofstream outfile("2.txt");

    if(myfile.is_open())
    {
        while (getline(myfile,line))
            outfile<<"@"<<line<<std::endl;

        myfile.close();
    }
    else 
        std::cout << "Woops, couldn't open file!" << std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```